# On the annihilator of a certain quotient module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $\mathcal F $ be the collection of all non-cyclic submodules of $M$ and suppose $\mathcal F$ is non-empty. Then by Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element say $N$. Now let $P=Ann _R (M/N)=\{x \in R : xM \subseteq N\}$ .

My question is : If $P\ne R$, then is $P$ a prime ideal of $R$ ?

I was going by contradiction. Let $ab \in P$ but $a,b \notin P$ . Then $N \subsetneq N+aM, N+bM$ . So that $N+aM$ and $N+bM$ are cyclic submodules of $M$. If I can show that this implies $N$ is cyclic, then we are done. Let $N+aM=R(n_1+am_1)$ for $n_1 \in N , m_1 \in M$ . Let $L :=\{m \in M : am \in N\}$. Then $N \subseteq L$ and since $ab M \subseteq N$, so $bM \subseteq L$ . So $N+bM \subseteq L$ , so $L$ is cyclic let $L=Rl$ for some $l \in L$ .I can show that $N=Rn_1+aL$ , but unfortunately that's not enough.

Please help .

Comment: I'm not convinced that $\mathcal F$ need have a maximal element.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Why not ... ? The only thing needs to be checked that any totally ordered  subset $\{N_i\}$ of $\mathcal F$  has an upper bound . Indeed $K=\cup_i N_i$ serves as an upper bound : It is a submodule since $N_i$ s are totally ordered by inclusion . Moreover, if $K$ is singly generated by some $m \in K$, then $m \in N_i$ for some $i$, and then $K=Rm \subseteq N_i \subseteq K$ , so $N_i=Rm$ is cyclic , no!!. Thus $K$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Why can't your $K$ equal $M$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I didn't get  your question ... is there any problem if $K=M$ ?

Comment: What then is $Ann(M/K)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Sorry for the confusion. I am assuming $P \ne R$. I have edited it into the question body. Although, I must point out, that $\mathcal F$, if non-empty, will always have a maximal element. My argument with Zorn's lemma shows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [1, Corollary 5.6], $N$ is a prime submodule of $M$ when $M$ is cyclic. Hence, $Ann_R(M/N)=(N:_RM)$ is a prime ideal  of $R$. Now in general cass, if $N=M$, then $Ann_R(M/N)=R$ and so the problem is not true in this cass and if $N\not= M$, then $M$ if cyclic by the maximality of $N$ and the problem is true by above argument.

[1] R. Nekooei and E. Rostami, A Prime Submodule Principle,Algebra Colloq. 21, 697 (2014). 
https://doi.org/10.1142/S1005386714000649